# Simplify jQuery animation with callback

Tags: javascript, jquery

Looking for feedback on how to better improve the code below to simplify the code below.

```
var animateTop = $('body');
if ($('html').hasClass('lt-ie9')) {
    animateTop = $('html');
}
$('.var').on('click', function() {
    animateTop.animate({
        scrollTop: $('footer').offset().top
    }, {
    queue: false,
    duration: 1500,
    complete: function() {
        if(!$('.foo').hasClass('active')) {
            $('.foo').toggleClass('active');
            $('.bar').slideToggle();    
        }
    }
});                
return false;
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't really tell what your code does in real life, thus the following optimization/organization might not work. However, following generic tips, here's what I got:

```
//we can reduce DOM fetching by fetching html first
//caching it as well as other frequently used elements
//assuming that they never change in the course of your page's life
var html = $('html')
  , footer = $('footer')
  , foo = $('.foo')
  , bar = $('.bar')
  , options = {
      queue: false,
      duration: 1500,
      complete: function () {
        if (!foo.hasClass('active')) {
          foo.toggleClass('active');
          bar.slideToggle();
        }
      }
    }
  ;

//then here, we fetch body only when it's not IE9+ thus reducing operations
html = html.hasClass('lt-ie9') ? html : $('body');

$('.var').on('click', function (e) {

  //i think the properties can't be cached since it may need current values
  //however, your options can be cached since they are static values
  html.animate({
    scrollTop: footer.offset().top
  }, options);

  //an answer as to when to use return false vs preventDefault
  //you can use either, depending on the situation
  //http://stackoverflow.com/a/1357151/575527
  return false;
});
```